# Why must a 'user.' be prepended to the name when setting a file's xattr with os.setxattr()?

Tags: python, operating-system, xattr

I am saving data that I guess could be deemed metadata on a JSON serialized file:

```
os.setxattr('/var/tmp/test.json', 'user.keyname', b'value')
```

and I can get the bytes value back via:

```
os.getxattr('/var/tmp/test.json', 'user.keyname')
```

The only way I can get this to work is by putting `user.` in front of the key/name that I want to use. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/extend-attr.html

> On Linux, specifically, four categories of extended attributes have been defined :
>
> - **trusted**: to record properties which should only be accessed by the kernel,
> - **security**: to record security properties of a file,
> - **system**: to record other system related properties on which the file owner has some  control,
> - **user**: to record properties defined by applications.
>
> The names of the extended attributes must be prefixed by the name of the category and a dot, hence these categories are generally qualified as name spaces.